# Javascript Delete operator is removing two properties

Tags: javascript, for-loop, delete-operator

This code, even though I'm using very unique uuidv4 tags for the property names.

```
for( const key in this.entity_array ) {
    let ref = this.entity_array[ key ]
    if( ref.is_this_selected )
        delete this.entity_array[ key ]
}
```

... is causing weird behaviour. When adding elements it will not show until two properties exist and when only two are left it is deleting both properties even though they have different property names.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `this.entity_array ` array or object?

Comment: Can you post the content of `this.entity_array` ?

Comment: What is `ref.is_this_selected` for? Could you post the code for this as well please?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I guess debugger is your best friend. Debug it.

Comment: This had me for a few hours, but ended up being a logic error in the end

Comment: I will post more code next time, thank you for reading.